# How to change x-axis and y-axis value in r other than default plot by R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the code:

```
ggplot(percent, aes(x = user_id , y = percentage, label = final_rank)) + 
geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, nudge_y = 5,nudge_x = 1,size = 5, color = "blue") + 
geom_point(color = "red")`
```

This is the Plot I am getting:

[image: Plot between User Ids and Percentage of Prediction].

As shown in this image

[image: The Final Prediction, csv file image]

the x-axis values were default as 1000, 2000 etc and y-axis default values 25, 75, 100 etc. But  I want the x-axis values to be changed as respective user_ids (1163, 2080 = in x-axis) and prediction percentage(0.91,0.833 etc = in y-axis) like =
1,2,3 points are showing ranks respective to user_id and percentage.
[1163 rank is 1 with 0.91(91%), 2080 rank is 2 with 0.83(83%)]

[image: I want plot as shown in this image]

As Suggested
Suppose iris data set `head(iris)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa`
so after taking Sepal.Length in x-axis and Sepal.Width in y-axis.
I need x-axis labels need to be respective as shown above. Like x-axis need to be `5.1` `4.9` and y-axis need to be `3.5` `3.0` with respective species `setosa` in the plots [iris dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjo9M.jpg). Not as in plot `7.0 , 7.5` breaks and `6 , 7 , 8` breaks

Comment: Please post your data.  Also, have you tried adding `scale_x_continuous()` and setting the `breaks` argument to the values you want?

Comment: @BenG Data is as shown in IMAGE -> The Final Prediction, csv file image (file name). or **consider the data may be whatever** and also tried scale_x_continuous() but not getting the output.

Comment: Still, if you would post some random data, it would be much easier for everyone to recreate your problem.. otherwise everyone has to create some dummy data in order to help you, which is slighlty annoying..

Comment: @SeGa Suggested edits are added to my question thank you and please correct me if I am anywhere wrong and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this . . .

```
library(tidyvsere)

iris %>%
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
    ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = iris$Sepal.Length)
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you so much i got the output. Thank you for valuable suggestions and answers.. Many Thanks  and also Thanks to all.

Comment: @SANDESHSAMAKA, no problem.  Just check the answer box so the question can be marked answered.